# Limit regex scope to match items only in a section of code

Tags: regex

This is a general regex question.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
function (item1, item2, item3) {
    var item4 = null
    var item5 = null
}
```

I know that's javascript, but I don't want a javascript-specific answer: I'm curious about a pure regex answer.

Suppose I want to write regex that matches any word that starts with "item", but I *only* want matches that are between parenthesis.

So my question: is there a way to write a regex query that matches everything that starts with `item` but is also between parens? Like a way to limit my regex scope to just things within parens?

UPDATE: Just so people know, I am asking because I am working on language support for Atom (the text editor), which (to my knowledge) supports only pure regex to match patterns to add language styling. Because of this, I'm stuck with pure regex, even though I am parsing JS.

Comment: which parenthesis you mean?

Comment: Did you try: `/\([^)]*?item[^)]*\)/`

Answer (score 0):

Pull out parenthesized things, then look inside them.

```js
str="function (item1, item2, item3) {\
    var item4 = null\
    var item5 = null\
}";

var results = [].concat(
    str.match(/\(.*?\)/g)
        .map(function(submatch) {
            return submatch.match(/\bitem\w*\b/g);
        })
);

document.write(results);
```

This code first calls `String#match` to retrieve all the parenthesized portions of the input, so in this case it returns `['(item, item2, item3)']` (an array with one element). Then it calls `Array#map` on that array, transforming each element into a list of matches for `item*` (the `\b` matches word boundaries, and `\w` matches alphanumerics). Since the result is now a nested array (`[['item1', 'item2', item3']]`), we use `Array#concat` to flatten it out.

Comment: I know that's possible, but I want to know from a general regex standpoint if there is a way to limit search scope.

Comment: @isaachess I'm afraid you've fallen victim to the "monolithic regexp-itis" disease, an Ebola-like virus the symptoms of which are to attempt to solve every problem with one single huge regexp. What I did was **exactly** to limit search scope, by using one regexp to extract the scope, then another to search within it. If you absolutely insist on doing this in a single regexp, then there are probably ways involving negative or positive look-aheads or look-behinds or look-arounds or what have you, but honestly, what's the point? You'll just end up with something unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: Haha, I completely understand. The reason I am asking is because I'm working on a language support package for Atom (text editor), which limits me to using purse regex -- so I don't have any choice in the matter. Plus, I am still curious to know if it is _possible_, if only to increase my understanding of regex.

Comment: Assuming then the relevant flavor is JS?

Comment: You should add the note about Atom to your question, because otherwise people might question your sanity in trying to "parse" JS with regexps.

Comment: Fair enough. Actually, the engine isn't JS as far as I can tell, because I've been able to do things already that supposedly aren't supported in JS regex. I don't know what it's using instead. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?:[^()]*(?=\()|[^()]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|item\w+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/6)

Comment: What regexp flavor is this?

Comment: Pcerl Compatible Regular expression which was included in languages such as Perl, PHP, R